# Framerate decreases after multiple video file loads on my MediaPipe Pose Detection Webserver

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, mediapipe, pose-detection

I am working on a MediaPipe solution where a user can choose a video on my web server, and then view the video with pose detection landmarks on top of the video. The following solution works ok, but after selecting +3 videos, the framerate decreases significantly.

Is there too much data loaded in the browser? Should I do something to clear MediaPipe Pose when selecting a new video?

I was also wondering if its better performance-wise to upload the video on a server, instead of selecting a local file?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <label>Select video: <input id="video_upload" type="file"></label><br>

    <div class="container" id="container">
      <video id="input_video" loop muted hidden crossorigin="anonymous"></video>
      <canvas class="output_canvas" width="820px" height="462px"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script type="module">

        import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/camera_utils/camera_utils.js";
        import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/control_utils/control_utils.js";
        import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/drawing_utils/drawing_utils.js";
        import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/pose/pose.js";

        const videoUpload = document.getElementById("video_upload");
        const videoElement = document.getElementById("input_video");
        const canvasElement = document.getElementsByClassName("output_canvas")[0];
        const canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");

        videoUpload.onchange = function (event) {
          let file = event.target.files[0];
          let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
          videoElement.src = blobURL;

          videoElement.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
            startEstimation(videoElement);
          });
        };

        function startEstimation(video) {
          let width = video.videoWidth;
          let height = video.videoHeight;

          canvasElement.width = width;
          canvasElement.height = height;

          video.play();

          async function detectionFrame(now, metadata) {
            video.playbackRate = 0.8; // Play with 80% of speed to perform better processing of video
            videoElement.pause();
            await pose.send({ image: videoElement });
            video.requestVideoFrameCallback(detectionFrame);
          }
          video.requestVideoFrameCallback(detectionFrame);
        }

        const pose = new Pose({locateFile: (file) => {
            return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/pose/${file}`;
        }});

        pose.setOptions({
            modelComplexity: 1,
            smoothLandmarks: true,
            enableSegmentation: false,
            smoothSegmentation: true,
            minDetectionConfidence: 0.5,
            minTrackingConfidence: 0.5
        });

        pose.onResults(onResults);

        function onResults(results) {
            canvasCtx.save();
            canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
            canvasCtx.drawImage(results.image, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);

            canvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
            canvasCtx.drawImage(results.image, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
            canvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

            drawConnectors(canvasCtx, results.poseLandmarks, POSE_CONNECTIONS, { color: "#00FF00", lineWidth: 1});
            drawLandmarks(canvasCtx, results.poseLandmarks, { color: "#FF0000", radius: 0.5});

            videoElement.play();
            canvasCtx.restore();
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem in the past but in React. It appears that the problem lies in initializing the model multiple times, which can lead to a decrease in the framerate. To resolve this, make sure you're only initializing the model once in your code and also closing it correctly.

Unfortunately, since I primarily work with React, I may not be able to provide you with a more direct solution. But hope this give you some clarity towards resolving your issue.